# Why are numbers not treated as 'proper nouns'?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

Numbers are abstract concepts in themselves, why are they not treated as proper nouns when used as the subject of a sentence?

Other abstract concepts such as 'August' are used as proper nouns, why aren't numbers used in this way?

For example: 'two is a prime number'

In mathematical texts, a number is really treated mostly like a proper noun.

Comment: A number isn't a noun but a quantity, so is more like an adjective: "five beans". In maths, "five (unspecified) units". In physics, "five seconds (etc)." The ordinals certainly are: "first light", "King Charles III".

Comment: I don't understand: isn't "two is a prime number" an example of a sentence where the number "two" functions as a "proper noun"?

Comment: I think the fact it can act as both an adjective and noun is the reason.

Comment: @Frank yeah it is a noun, maybe not a 'proper noun'.

Comment: You are saying that in mathematical texts numbers are used as proper nouns and asking why they aren't used in this way??? See the discussion [Are numbers Nouns or Adjectives?](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/2wt35v/are_numbers_nouns_or_adjectives/):"*Numbers clearly aren't very good nouns (they cannot be modified by adjectives), or very good adjectives (they are not gradable, can't be modified by adverbs). I think numbers behave more like determiners, if you had to assign them a category.*"

Comment: @Conifold they are used as nouns, not 'proper nouns' (capitalised) as other unique *things* are.

Comment: Is the question why they are not capitalized like proper *names*? The sun and the moon aren't always capitalized either, and even in mathematics integers have [multiple realizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers), so they are not even exactly unique.

Comment: @Conifold true, but I was thinking in a simpler sense, contextually you can choose your realisation, or have the opinion that the *same* object can be viewed in different ways through different  means.

Comment: If one has that opinion they can capitalize them, but you are asking why such convention is not adopted by everybody. Probably, because people associate prototypical single copy tangible things with proper names and do not wish to bother with metaphysical analyses to decide when some abstractions can also be called "unique" (and that, in some nebulous sense). Even "equator" is not capitalized, and, unlike integers, it has a unique physical location.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: natural language is messy, contextual, and inconsistent.

Long answer: Proper nouns are used to specify definite objects with unique identities. Basically that means things that exist over time, which cannot have other things substituted in for them without loss of identity. Pope Francis, Chicago, and the Eiffel Tower are proper nouns because we can't substitute in another person, city, or building without people wondering what the f*** just happened. 'My suitcase' is not a proper noun because even though it's a singular, unique object, I could buy a new suitcase and it would become 'my suitcase' without anyone blinking twice.

Numbers like 'one' and 'two' are not considered proper nouns because they are not definite, unique objects. If I say "2 + 2 = 4" it seems immediately obvious that the first '2' is not the same object as the second '2' (if they were the same object, two plus two would likely equal two). There are multiple objects referred to by the label '2', which we can thus add together, and that multiplicity is merely obscured by the fact that we cannot definitely say what those objects are.

Comment: I find your statement about 2 + 2 interesting, because I would have said that it seems immediately obvious that the first 2 **is** the same object as the second 2. It's true that if you have two cats, and you also have another two cats, then the first two cats that you have are not the same cats as the other two cats. But if we erase and forget about the objects that these numbers quantify, and consider only the numbers themselves, then the result is that the first number is the very same number as the second number (namely, 2).

Comment: @TannerSwett: Yeah, my intuition is that there's a Venn Diagram issue here. I mean, in any elementary statistics course we learn that P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B): the sum of the probabilities minus the probability of any overlap. I suspect there's something similar implicit in addition. Something like C(A,B) = C(A) + C(B) - I(A,B), where C(...) means 'count of' and I(...) means 'identity of': count up the objects of each group and remove any objects common to both groups. But that's hard to represent in abstract mathematics.

Comment: @TedWrigley I have no clue what you are saying about 'different objects', this is not standard mathematical practice, unless you are speaking about some set theory concept, they are just symbols being used twice. There may be two things been counted. There maybe a difference between the groups, I'm interested in what you mean by this?

Comment: @TedWrigley reading your answer, I believe I am misunderstanding, by number you mean the 'label' each use of the 'label' is different? But the 'label' is the same?

Comment: @Confused: Yes. We have a label, but it isn't clear whether the thing pointed to is a distinct, unique 'object'. When we make the term concrete (e.g., point to '2 applies'), '2' becomes an adjective describing distinct countable objects. But used as a noun...? You might think about a function f(x). If I write f(2) I'll get an answer.  if I substitute '3' for '2' — f(3) — I'll get a somewhat different answer, but the function doesn't change in any way. That's atypical of proper nouns. Can we substitute a different person into the function of 'spouse' and expect the relationship to be unchanged?

Comment: @TedWrigley surely if '2' is a label, we can discuss this label using language, for example 'two is a number'? is a sentence with 'two' as a noun, I'm asking why 'two' isn't a proper noun (capitalised in sentences), I think the answer to this is that it can be used as an adjective as you point out.

Comment: @confused - "If I say "2 + 2 = 4" it seems immediately obvious that the first '2' is not the same object as the second '2'" Perfect... We use *numbers* to count things: at a certain point in time during the "evolution" of human species, we made a leap towards abstraction: we learn (?) to use numbers to count... themselves.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA of course, I'm still slightly unsure about 'the second '2'' is different from the first, these are just symbols recurring in a sentence, I'm confused by what you mean by 'perfect'.